# Quick group question on $GL(n)$

Tags: group-theory

Is $GL(n)$ (as a group) isomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$? $GL(n)$ denotes the general linear group of invertible $n\times n$ matrices (say over $\mathbb R^n$)

Comment: What makes you think so?

Comment: Matrices over $\mathbb{R}$, you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M \in \mathrm{GL}(n)$ such that $M$ is a diagonal matrix with $-1$ along the whole of the diagonal:
$$M = \left(\begin{matrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 & \\
0 & -1 & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & 0 & -1 & \\
& \vdots && \ddots \\
\end{matrix}\right)$$
Clearly, $M^2 = I$.

Now think of $\mathbb R^n$. There is no non-identity element of $\mathbb R^n$ of order $2$.
$$\therefore \forall n \in \mathbb N_+, \quad \mathrm{GL}(n) \not \cong \mathbb R^n$$

Answer (score 2):

Not for $n > 1$, because $GL(n)$ is non-abelian, while $\mathbb R^n$ is abelian for every $n \geq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

William Stagner's comment gives the answer for all $n > 1$. For the remaining case, you can note that $GL(1)$ has an element of order $2$, which $\mathbb{R}$ does not.